# How to get Ember to Lazy (async) Load hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Possibly I'm misunderstanding how Ember wants to lazy load `hasMany` sides of relationships but I'll specify what I want and someone can tell me if it is possible and how to configure things.

I'm using the `RESTAdapter` and I have a parent object with a 1-to-many relationship with several other objects. When I view the parent, I have links for the children objects that I want to show as child outlets.

Examples might be:

```
// brand.js
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string'),
  dateCreated: attr('date'),
  lastUpdated: attr('date'),
  regions: hasMany('region', {async: true})
});

// region.js
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  dateCreated: attr('date'),
  lastUpdated: attr('date'),
  brand: belongsTo()
});
```

When I access `/api/brands/1` I'm returning the following JSON:

```
{
  "brand": {
    "id": 1,
    "dateCreated": 1466456255539,
    "lastUpdated": 1466456255936,
    "name": "Some Brand",
    "description": "Voluptates odio nemo corrupti",
  }
}
```

I have my route defined like so:

```
this.route('brand', {path: '/brands/:brand_id'}, function() {
  this.route('regions');
});
```

So, in the `brand` detail screen, I have an `{{outlet}}` and when I click on the link for `regions`, I need to fetch the regions for that brand, and the URL would be `/api/brands/1/regions`.

Everything works if I return all the data in one big result, and my `regions` router looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.modelFor('brand').get('regions');
  }
});
```

But I don't know what to do so that regions gets lazily fetched correctly from my API. Or if it is even possible. I read up on `side loading` and currently, my API won't return ID's only for children.

Comment: one way would be to add query params to link-to: `{{#link-to "brand.regions" (query-params brand=model)}}` and then query for that brand in region-`Route`. [the docs for query-params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/routing/query-params/)

Comment: If you use the `regions` property anywhere in a template that gets activated, then Ember will automatically load the records for that relationship. Could you show us the template where you're actually displaying the regions?

Comment: @GJK - I can tomorrow when I'm at work but that makes a little sense. I can tell you that I'm *not* getting them via `{{brand.regions}}` and maybe if I access them that way, it will query differently. I'll try something like that and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example, ember.js does not know, what regions to load. Your JSON has to be either (non-embedded):

```
{
  "brand": {
    "id": 1,
    "dateCreated": 1466456255539,
    "lastUpdated": 1466456255936,
    "name": "Some Brand",
    "description": "Voluptates odio nemo corrupti",
    "regions": ["5", "9"]
  }
}
```

Which then loads regions with the id 5 and 9. Or you could embed them directly:

```
{
  "brand": {
    "id": 1,
    "dateCreated": 1466456255539,
    "lastUpdated": 1466456255936,
    "name": "Some Brand",
    "description": "Voluptates odio nemo corrupti",
    "regions": [{
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Hanover",
      "dateCreated": "2016-09-25 18:39:18",
      "lastUpdated": "2016-09-25 18:39:18",
    },{
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Cologne",
      "dateCreated": "2016-01-19 11:59:18",
      "lastUpdated": "2016-02-22 12:09:58",
    }]
  }
}
```

See [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) for the latter.

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of. I was hoping that Ember could infer the correct URL because of `regions'` parent; `/brands/1/regions` which is how the API currently works. It is problematic because currently, I'd have to have all the children embedded when the list is pulled (or figure out how to get it to look up the brand again when I'm on the detail view).

Comment: I was under the impression that the REST adapter could also handle fetching hasMany relationships via URLs. [This site](http://thejsguy.com/2016/02/21/handling-nested-resources-in-ember-data.html) seems to agree, but I'm not really _that_ familiar with Ember-Data any more.